# How to get data from FormGroup and add it oldest fake data

Tags: angular-services, angular-forms

i'm working on my first angular reactive form project , i have fakedata as a users data in service
and a sign up form , i want to get form values as a new user data and add it to my fake data ,
here what i have done

in Sign-UpComponent.ts

```
export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {
  
  SignUpForm: FormGroup;
  constructor( private fb:FormBuilder) {
    this.SignUpForm=this.fb.group({
      email:[ "" ,[Validators.required ,Validators.minLength(5), Validators.email , Validators.pattern("^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$")]],
      password:[ "" ,[Validators.required ,Validators.minLength(6)]] 
    }
  }  
  onSubmit(){
    let aaa=this.newUserData
    console.log(aaa);
  }  
  get newUserData(){ 
    const newUser:User[]=[{
      password:this.SignUpForm.controls.password.value,
      email : this.SignUpForm.controls.email.value,
    }]  
  return newUser;
  }
```

until here the console.log print the newUser with values as `[{email:"aaa@gmail.com",password:123456}]`

then i pass the newUser variable to the user service as the follow

```
export class UsersDataService {
  data:User[]=[{
    password:"123456",
    email:"bbb@gmail.com",
  }]

  newUser:User[]
  allUsers:User[]=[]


  getDataInfo(){
    this.allUsers=this.data.concat(this.newUser);
    return this.allUsers;
  }
  

  constructor(  SignUpComponent:SignUpComponent) {
    this.newUser= SignUpComponent.newUserData
   }
}
```

now should `console.log (allUsers)` be `[[{email:"bbb@gmail",password:123456}],[{email:"aaa@gmail",password:123456}]]`

but it show without values
`[[{email:bbb@gmail,password:123456}],[{email:"",password:""}]]`

Answer (score 1):

in the the SignupComponent i send the newUser data to service

```
  onSubmit(){
    this.newUserData()
  }  

  newUserData(){ 
    let newUser:User={
      password:this.SignUpForm.controls.password.value,
      email : this.SignUpForm.controls.email.value    }  
    this.UsersDataService.getNewUser(newUser);
  }
```

then i push it to the data[] in the user Service

```
export class UsersDataService {
  data:User[]=[{
    password:"123456",
    email:"aaa@gmail.com",
  }]
  
  constructor() {
  }


  getNewUser(newUser:User){
    this.data.push(newUser);
    
  }
  
  getDataInfo(){
    console.log(this.data);
    return this.data;
  }
  
}
```